# Outlook VSTO - how to show the "Invite attendees" textbox when I call appointment.Display()?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-2010, appointment

I have the following code to popup an outlook apptitem.  It works great except i can't see the actual attendees textbox on the popup unless i click "Invite Attendees".  When i click on that button on the appt item it does show the list of people that i have populated below.

```
 public void BookAppt(List<string> rooms, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        var PacktAppointmentItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
        PacktAppointmentItem.Subject = "Test Meeting";
        PacktAppointmentItem.Location = "My Room";
        PacktAppointmentItem.Start = startTime;
        PacktAppointmentItem.End = endTime;
        PacktAppointmentItem.Body = "Test Meeting";
        PacktAppointmentItem.RequiredAttendees = String.Join(";", rooms);
        PacktAppointmentItem.Display(true);
    }
```

Is there any way to how that textbox of attendees shown automatically without having to click on the "Invite Attendees" button?  Also, is there anyway to programatically call "Check names" so the attendees are resolved?

Comment: You can "check names" by calling the `ResolveAll()` method on the `AppointmentItem.Recipients` object. I don't know the answer to the other part of the question though, but maybe the `FormProperties` object has to do with that.

Comment: @John Willernse - thanks for the ResolveAll() as that worked . . hopefully someone will come back with the first question (I thought it might be a parameter on the display method but can't find it there or on any property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a MeetingItem, and not an AppointmentItem.  You can't directly create a MeetingItem, but you're almost there anywhere:  just add this line in your code:

```
PacktAppointmentItem.MeetingStatus = Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
```

So your final code should like

```
var PacktAppointmentItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
PacktAppointmentItem.Subject = "Test Meeting";
PacktAppointmentItem.Location = "My Room";
PacktAppointmentItem.Start = DateTime.Now;
PacktAppointmentItem.MeetingStatus = Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
PacktAppointmentItem.End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1.0);
PacktAppointmentItem.Body = "Test Meeting";
PacktAppointmentItem.RequiredAttendees = String.Join(";", rooms);
PacktAppointmentItem.Display(true);
```

Quick background: From microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.meetingitem(v=office.14).aspx

> Unlike other Microsoft Outlook objects, you cannot create this [e.g.
>   MeetingItem] object. It is created automatically when you set the
>   MeetingStatus property of an AppointmentItem object to olMeeting and
>   send it to one or more users. They receive it in their inboxes as a
>   MeetingItem.

Comment: thanks Magnum for the solution . .i knew there had to be a way :)